# Can one access the Arguments "class" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

All other built-ins are attached to the global object:

```
> Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date)
'[object Date]'
> new Date instanceof Date
true
> Object.prototype.toString.call(new Function)
'[object Function]'
> new Function instanceof Function
true
> Object.prototype.toString.call(new Number)
'[object Number]'
> new Number instanceof Number
true
```

`Arguments`, however, is not:

```
> args = null; (function() { args = arguments }()); Object.prototype.toString.call(args)
'[object Arguments]'
> new Arguments instanceof Arguments
ReferenceError: Arguments is not defined
```

Is there any way to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to manually create an instance of `Arguments`, then it's not possible. There is no `Arguments` constructor function.

Objects of that type are actually created by an internal algorithm (see [section 10.6](http://es5.github.com/#x10.6) of the ECMAScript specification). What you see as the output of `Object.prototype.toString.call` is just the value stored in the `[[Class]]` internal property of the object. It could be anything. In this case, the specification defines it should be set to the string "Arguments".

Comment: I don't want to create an Arguments instance, but I would like to access the Arguments constructor. `(new Date).constructor === Date`, but `args.constructor === Object`.

Comment: Because there isn't an Arguments constructor. Its prototype is the default Object prototype, whose constructor is Object.